# Applying Gauss's Law on a Non-Uniform Conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

I've seen tons of examples of Gauss's Law applied to solve for electric field. However, the only shape its ever really applied to is a cylindrical or spherical Gaussian surface.

I'm looking at a stator winding, and I'm curious as to how to apply Gauss's Law. Unfortunately, I don't even know where to start.

An example of the stator winding I'm looking at is shown below. Note that the application of Gauss's Law implies this is an electrostatic scenario. In the example below, how would I, for example, find the E-field at point 'x', or anywhere in the stator winding? (Note: the bronze color represents the copper conductors, and the blue enclosing rectangle, represents insulation.)
[image]

Comment: Gauss’ Law in integral form wouldn’t be so useful here as it only simplifies things when there is a lot of symmetry. That’s why you see it in spherical/cylindrical symmetric contexts. Here you’ll probably need to solve some differential equations. Do you have some information about the 3D configuration of this object? Also, how about the amount of charge on each conducting cell?

Comment: Please understand that the reason why your previous question didn't get answer is probably that this is an engineering problem. This problem does not have much symmetry. As such, it will probably require complex calculations by a computer to be solved (kind of like weather prediction) and simply cannot be solved by hand here.

Comment: @GabrielGolfetti Stator windings in generators typically have only one common 3D configuration. It's a complex configuration, so you'll have to look it up, simply search 'stator windings'. I'm sure that Gauss's Law can be applied to factor in Cartesian coordinates (x, y, and/or z). Regardless, do you know what sorts of equations/formulas would help me solve the E-field at any point for this sort of conductor?

Comment: @AnuragBaundwal Do you know of any such software that would generate a formula for a conductor that I would build in the software? I've used software such as ANSYS Maxwell, and COMSOL, but they don't offer those sorts of features.

Comment: Well, you need to give us some more data then. Is there electric current between the cells? Should we expect magnetic fields to be relevant? The fact that the thing is copper and not say, gold, is relevant?

Comment: All of this is necessary when trying to solve a problem like this numerically, since you’ll need a complete set of boundary conditions for Maxwell’s Equations (which is what you’ll be using to solve the model)

Comment: @John Sorry but I'm only a highschool student and an absolute beginner when it comes to programming. However, I would admit that I exaggerated a lot when comparing your problem to weather prediction — yours should need a much simpler code. Maybe someone at stack overflow could write the code for you (if the code happens to be simple enough), or at least tell you the name of some relevant softwares.

Comment: @John " ... In the example below, how would I, for example, find the E-field at point 'x', or anywhere in the stator winding? ..." I don't know about the field at the point x, but the field **inside** a conductor is zero if there is no current flowing.